# Can I ask a question about bed frames on Home Improvement?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I need to ask a question about bed frames and head boards is that going to fly here?

Answer (score 8):

depends on the question.  If you ask what ones to buy or what size, then probably not.  If you are asking how to build them, repair an existing one, or modify one, then absolutely!

Comment: What if I'm trying to determine the type of bed frame I have.

Comment: type as in astetics (traditional, modern, contemporary, etc) - probably not.  Or type as in king, queen, etc?  It does not hurt, just ask, we wont bite!